# Every Console.log is running twice in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

Originally I was going to title this, **Is componentDidMount() Better than useEffect with dependency array []?**

I have two different react projects.

**Project A** was made using version "react": "^16.14.0",

**Project B** was made with version "react": "^18.2.0",

in **Project A** I used componentDidMount mostly for performing state change/api pulls/ etc and console.log on top to make sure the componentDidMount life-cycle ran only onces.

in **Project B** I am using useEffect to perform similar actions, and again I have a console.log right on top to make sure the useEffect (life cycle) runs only one... it does not, it runs TWICE. And I am very very confused Why on Earth would it be run twice? Has anyone else ran into such an issue? The code is a very simple console.log

```
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("app()")
  },[])
```

I Expect it to run ONLY ONCE, but it runs twice.

Additionally, I even have a useMemo with the dependency which console.log twice instead of once. I am certain my implementation is correct. The code works, the UI displays data as expected.

As a matter of fact EVERY Console.log is running twice in **Project B** . Has anyone else run into an issue where they get Extra console.log, and how did you resolve it?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). In development mode only, it will mount every component twice to help catch accidental impurities in your code.

Comment: thank you @Unmitigated Yes it is running on StrikeMode. And your saying this will happen in dev mod only but will never happen in deployment? How do I turn off as i find this feature annoying to work with.

Comment: @adnantariq Yes, this is only to help during development. Each component will only be mounted once in production.